# Do "ou" certified greens need to be washed and checked?

Tags: kashrut-kosher

If a salad mix of greens just has a plain "ou", does it require checking?

Comment: Rolled back to revision 1 on the grounds that every hashgacha is different and asking for a general hashgacha is too broad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the [OU](https://www.ou.org/news/keeping_veggies_free_of_bugs_and_yes_do_this_at_home/) on individual products that carry the OU certification mark, it is not necessary to do further checking.